# Am I allowed to accept payment to my US bank account, after leaving the US? (I was on F1 visa, I have no SSN)

Tags: banking, legal, visa, immigration

Am I allowed to accept payment to my US bank account, after leaving the US? (I was on F1 visa, I have no SSN, I never worked in the US)

I don't even know if I'm allowed to have a bank account after leaving the US. I don't have any ties to US anymore.

I probably won't visit US again.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the bank knows your visa / citizenship status (because they require to tell them when you open the account)  and most banks are reluctant to keep your account open once you are no longer living in the US.
You will find that out when your bank contacts you about it, or if they do not have your new address, when they close your account on you.

Aside from that, you can of course receive payments in your account. There is no way any regulatory or governmental institution would even know about it, and anyway, they wouldn't care.

Note that depending on who makes those payments and for what, they *could* be taxable events, and if so, the IRS would expect you to file US taxes for them.

Comment: Am I allowed to work for a US company as an individual who has no ties to the US? Shouldn't that be illegal according to the US? I think they must have a system to prevent me from paying taxes (therefore my accounts would be blocked or something if I receive payments).

Comment: You seem to have a funny understanding of 'illegal'. Of course you can work for a US company. The company will either deduct taxes before paying you, or - if you ar not employed, but a contractor - furnish you a respective form. You are required to file for and pay your taxes (if any), and the only thing illegal is if you don't do that.

Comment: I'm just trying to play safe. I have no connections in the US and I'm a 3rd world citizen

Comment: Well then its pretty perfect. Just pay taxes and I can work for any US company?? That's even better than having H1B visa for me. BTW I just remembered I filled out https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf form while creating my bank account. You still think I'm good or nah?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. I don't think there's anything that prevents you from keeping a bank account you've already opened just because you left the country. If you're unsure, you could **contact your bank** and let them know you've moved out of the country and they'll probably advise you on if there's anything that needs to change.

Comment: I bet IRS would also say I don't see why not when it comes to finding a reason to do something I don't like. From what I understand there is no right or wrong in law or elsewhere. There's only what you can get away with. Hence my worry.